# Small program to calculate prime numbers not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax, visual-studio-2015, syntax-error

Upon completion this program will output all prime numbers up to 1000, it is a fairly simple program and although I have read and re-read over the syntax many times at this point it is still not working

The code has been edited since the original post, it now runs with 0 errors, however it will not display the correct result, instead it displays 008D1389 over and over again.

[image]

this is the code in its entirety:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//funtion prototypes
int output_number, number = 1, value = 1,  i;
bool is_this_number_prime(int number_in_question);
bool does_it_have_factors(int numerator, int denominator);
int prime_number_sender();
int prime_number_output();

//function definitions
int prime_number_output()
{
    int value;
    value = prime_number_sender();
    return value;
}
int prime_number_sender()
{
    int value = number;
    if (is_this_number_prime(number) == true)
        return value;
    else
        return 0;

}



bool is_this_number_prime(int number_in_question)
{
    bool answer = true;
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (does_it_have_factors(number, i) == true)
            answer = false;
    }
    return answer;
}

bool does_it_have_factors(int numerator, int denominator)
{
        bool result = false;

if (numerator % denominator == 0){
    bool result = true;
}
return result;

}
int main() {

bool is_this_number_prime(int number_in_question);
bool does_it_have_factors(int numerator, int denominator);
int prime_number_sender(int number_in_question);
int prime_number_output();
int output_number = prime_number_output();
int i;
for (i = 2; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    cout << prime_number_output << endl;
    number++;
}
    return 0;


}
```

If anyone can shed any light as to why the code is not working I will be extremely grateful. Thankyou.

Comment: You declare/define `int prime_output(int value);`, but use it as `prime_output();`. Value should be a local variable, not an argument.

Comment: Fix your indentation and you will see that `void user_selection()` doesn't have the closing `}`.

Comment: off topic: do a web search for "Sieve of Eratosthenes"

Comment: In `main()`, `void user_selection();` is just a (locally-scoped) function prototype, so it doesn't actually call the function.  You need to change it to `user_selection();` (remove the `void`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generating quite a few errors for me.

> main.cpp|48|error: too few arguments to function 'int prime_output(int)'|

You have `prime_output` declared as `int prime_output(int value)` but you promptly shadow the parameter `value` with a local variable `value`. You might as well drop the parameter, it's not doing you any good.

> main.cpp|52|error: too few arguments to function 'int perfect_output(int)'|

Same issue as above. It looks like you're trying to modify the parameter directly, though, which is a no-no the way you're doing it. Try using a reference:

```
int perfect_output(int& value)
```

The function itself is weird as heck though. You don't output anything or do any calculations. I feel like you may not have finished writing that yet.

> main.cpp||In function 'void user_selection()':|
>   main.cpp|59|error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token|

This is probably where you're getting the error your question mentions. Your formatting makes it difficult to see this directly; fortunately Code::Blocks tells me where the problem is.

```
void user_selection()
{
```

You never close this. (More accurately, your closing brace is all the way at the end of the file, where it triggers *another* mismatch error.)

> main.cpp|87|error: expected declaration before '}' token|

See above. This is the closing brace that somehow got detached from `user_selection`. Try to be more careful with your code formatting; the easier you can read it, the easier you can see things like this before the compiler does.

> main.cpp|63|error: expected primary-expression before '<' token|

Your if statement is formatted oddly. Change `= <` to `<=` like this:

```
for (i = 2; i <= 1000; i++)//if numbers are 1 off, make i = 1.
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I have re designed the program using the techniques you have described above, the question has been edited to contain the new code. there are no errors, which is encouraging, but the program does still not run correctly. I do not recognise the erroneous output so I am not sure where to start the fault finding process. Can you see where this code is failing ??

Comment: If your code is the same as posted above, I can see half-a-dozen places where it needs fixing. However, I would suggest asking a new question since your compilation errors, the subject of this question, have been resolved.